# Material UI, Custom vertical stepper React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a code sandbox of Material UI's custom horizontal stepper.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-mk29p?file=/demo.js

The only difference is on line 229, I change the orientation to vertical

As you can see it completely bugs out.

Any help is appreciated, im not sure there is some issue with the custom css etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it's `alternativeLabel` combined with `vertical` that does it, as you can find about this prop in https://material-ui.com/api/stepper/

> If set to 'true' and orientation is horizontal, then the step label will be positioned under the icon.

just remove it and subtitles will be next to your vertical oriented icons

Comment: thanks for the insight, I removed alternativeLabel, but the connector lines are still horizontal.
Hopefully, this is a simple CSS thing, but that's really not my thing..  I tried flexDirection, and that's about all i got..
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ywxod?file=/demo.js

Comment: @Tom Add line style for ColorlibConnector component. Set height to let's say 10, and set width to 3 or whatever you like, then try to manipulate padding to set the postition of the line, hope it helps. Forked your codesandbox, look:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6d381?file=/demo.js:2020-2037